# ERROR AL GENERAR CERTIFICADO DE FIRMAS APK

Tags: android, apk

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de generar un APK en Android Studio, cada vez que voy a generar el certificado de firmas, me da este mensaje: 
"El almacén de claves JKS utiliza un formato propietario. Se recomienda migrar a PKCS12 que es un formato stándar del sector que utiliza "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore".

La verdad que he mirado en el foro, y he visto una pregunta similar, pero era enfocada a subirlo a google drive, que en este caso, no tiene nada que ver con mi problema.

La verdad que me sería de gran ayuda el saber que es lo que hago mal, porque no encuentro mucha información al respecto, y siguiendo la documentación oficial, no encuentro que esté haciendo algo diferente:
Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Hola Freddye Agrega por favor como generaste el certificado?

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Estoy siguiendo literlamente la forma que dice Android Developer.      Build - Generate Signed Bundle / APK - cuando genero la ruta y el nombre de certificado de firmas y el apk, me da el mensaje este de error. El certificado lo genera, pero al subir el APK a la consola, me vuelve a decir que el certificado de firma no ha usado el formato propietario.

Comment: Para firmar estas usando un .jks verdad? creaste el certificado desde la consola o desde android studio?

Comment: Sí, lo estoy creando en formato  .jks, lo estoy haciendo desde Android Studio. La cuestión es que he probado a hacerlo desde consola y me da el mismo error. 
Busco información al respecto tanto en español como en inglés y la verdad que pocos casos similares. 
He desinstalado Android Studio y he vuelto a instalar y nada. 
Por el mensaje que me genera, llego a la conclusión de que está generando el certificado en formato propietario, y lo tengo que transformar a formato PCKS12.

Comment: He conseguido arreglarlo, por si a alguien alguna vez le sucede, después de haber generado diferentes certificado de firmas por consola, con los formatos: .jks, .keystore, .p12 . Al final la solución, ha sido eliminar la ficha de aplicación que tenía guardada en Goggle Play Console, parece que se queda con un primer certificado de firmas y no me estaba permitiendo hacer la subida.